# RestClient.shared.send throws timed out error

Tags: ios

Is it possible to increase the time out for a request?

I have tried batch request in postman, this spends more than 80 seconds.
But on an iPad, I was faced with an error "time out" that throws after 60 seconds.

This error throws in this file SFRestAPI.m (297 line).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @comminty, I use this library SalesforceMobileSDK-iOS, I found this site link there. There indicated I can ask here any question. I have a problem, SDK return time out after 60 seconds, and my question is can I increase this time out, for example to 120 seconds.